# In codeship, what is the syntax to use env variables in steps?

Tags: codeship

In codeship - I am trying to use the env variables. My setup looks like this:

**codeship-services.yml**

```
environment:
  - ENV=my-var
```

**codeship-steps.yml**

```
type: parallel
steps:
  - command: echo $ENV
```

I does not work, it just prints $ENV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are only available when you the command is invoked in the context of a shell. By default that's not the case (similar to how `docker run` operates as well).

To get access to environment variables, either extract the command to a shell script and call the script instead, or explicitly invoke a shell

```
- service: app
  command: sh -c "echo $ENV"
```